# How can i get the month before to current date?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

Today its 28 jul Thursday 2022,

i want to get the 6 last months before to july

i want to get the 12 las months before to july

i was trying like this for 6 month

```js
var d = new Date();
const month= d.setDate(d.getDate() - 180).getMonth()
console.log(month)
```

i need in text, jun, may and so on

Comment: Have you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) can be used to create a date formatter which will produce localized month names according to your preference. The [constructor documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#locales) says this about using the default locale:

> To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array.

In the example below, I've chosen the `{month: "short"}` format (based on the expected output in your question), but you can change the options to suit your preference.

Then create a copy of the input date and subtract one month at a time to create the target month names. Here's a functional solution:

```js
'use strict';

/** Wraps a (potentially-negative) integer to a positive value less than the ceiling */
function uInt (ceil, n) {
  while (n < 0) n += ceil;
  return n % ceil;
}

function getPreviousNMonths (n, date = new Date()) {
  // Create a copy of the input date to keep the function pure
  const d = new Date(date.getTime());
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], {month: 'short'});
  const names = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    const monthIndex = uInt(12, d.getMonth() - 1);
    d.setMonth(monthIndex);
    names.push(formatter.format(d));
  }

  return names;
}


// Use:

// Initialize a date
const date = new Date(0);

// Adjust the date to the local date according to the details in your question
date.setFullYear(2022);
date.setMonth(6);
date.setDate(28);

const previous6MonthNames = getPreviousNMonths(6, date);
const previous12MonthNames = getPreviousNMonths(12, date);

console.log({previous6MonthNames, previous12MonthNames});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) and then [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get the month name in text.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6)
console.log(d.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'short'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [package](https://momentjs.com) for the calendar:

```js
import moment from 'moment';
    

moment().add(10, 'days').calendar(); // use this to add days, months or year in add parameter.
```

Comment: for 6 month ago how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop with current month, save index and print in short month format with [Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) No need extra library.
I created dynamic function you can get nth last months (1-11)

```js
function getLastNthMonths(amount) {
  if (amount > 11) throw 'Invalid amount';
  let listMonths = [];
  let currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  let traverseMonth = currentMonth + 1;
  while (traverseMonth !== currentMonth) {
    listMonths.push(traverseMonth++);
    traverseMonth %= 12;
  }

  //retrieve result

  const resultMonths = []
  for (let month of listMonths.slice(12 - amount - 1,12)) {
    const tempDate = new Date();
    tempDate.setDate(15);
    tempDate.setMonth(month);
    resultMonths.push(tempDate.toLocaleString("default", { month: "short" }));
  }
  return resultMonths;
}


getLastNthMonths(6) //get last 6 months
```