# how can i know the month and the day before from the current day?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

now its 28 jul i want to get the 7 days before the current date

```js
let daysWithMonth = []
for (let i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    const d = new Date();
    const day = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - i)).getDate()
    if(i%5==0){
      daysWithMonth.push(day)
    }
}

console.log(daysWithMonth)
```

but in my list i would like to know the month more, like this 7 jul, 28 jun

Comment: [You directed me here from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73160887/how-can-i-get-the-month-before-to-current-date/73161035?noredirect=1#comment129211802_73161035): If you're going to be manipulating date information, it'll be more convenient to work with an established codebase which exists for exactly that purpose (e.g. [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon/) — and its [tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luxon)), rather than re-implementing these algorithms from scratch.

Comment: @jsejcksn can you help me with luxon please

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161313/how-can-i-know-the-month-and-the-day-before-from-the-current-day?noredirect=1#comment129212552_73161313) Anything that I would say to you about Luxon would be sourced directly from the repository that I linked you to in the comment above. You can find everything there (including links to more documentation, usage guides, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let currentDate = new Date();
let prevDate = currentDate;
let prevDates = [];
let daysBefore = 7;
let options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
for(let i=1;i <= daysBefore;i++){
    prevDate = new Date(prevDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    prevDates.push(prevDate.toLocaleDateString(undefined,options))
} 
console.log(currentDate.getDate()) //Current Date
console.log(prevDates) //Previous 7 date
```

Comment: i need 28 jul, 27 jul ...

Comment: I have updated the code. Please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: i dont need the year

Comment: You just need to mention what you want in the options. You can remove year in the options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).